# Behavior of Treeset when an element changes while traversal

Tags: java

A newbie question perhaps, what happens if I change an element in a TreeSet, while traversing it? Would this lead to re-ordering of the element in the set?

Comment: Well, try it and see:) Also, if by traversal you mean iterate through with an iterator and by change you mean add/delete, then read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6460320/using-iterator-on-a-treeset

Comment: The examples there are adding/removing an element. What if I modify the element itself, while iterating? (I am trying in the mean while :))

Comment: well, you have a nice answer now:) +1 for trying it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Would this lead to re-ordering of the element in the set?

No, mutating an element inside a set does not lead to re-ordering of the tree set. You should never do that, because once you make a mutation that changes the order, your element may get lost in the tree. What you should do is removing the element, mutating its properties that change ordering, and then re-inserting it back.

Consider this example class:

```
class Student : Comparable<Student> {
    private String name;
    public Student(String name) {this.name = name;}
    public final String getName() {return name;}
    public final void setName(String name) { this.name = name;}
    public int compareTo<Student>(Student other) {
        return name.compareTo(other.name);
    }
}
```

If you make a tree set like this

```
TreeSet<Student,Integer> gradeInMath = ...
```

and then decide to change student's name when it's already in the set, you should do it like this:

```
Student nameChangeStudent = new Student("Joe");
Integer theGrade = gradeInMath.remove(nameChangeStudent);
nameChangeStudent.setName("Jack");
gradeInMath.put(nameChangeStudent, theGrade);
```

As you can see, this is not pretty at all. That's why as a general rule you should prefer *immutable* keys for your maps, both hash-based and tree-based.