# TreeSet Update Object Value seems to be a Bug in Implementation

Tags: java, collections, treeset

I was checking tree set and notice that I am unable to update the value in Tree set for my user defined Object

e.g

```
class Emp implements Comparable<Emp>
{
int id;
String name;

public Emp(int id,String name)
{
    this.id=id;
    this.name=name;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Emp obj) {
        if(obj.id>this.id)
            return -1;
        else if(obj.id<this.id)
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Emp Id:"+id+" Emp Name:"+name;
}
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    treesetwithCustom();
}

public static void treesetwithCustom()
{
    TreeSet<Emp> set=new TreeSet<Emp>();
    set.add(new Emp(1,"ABC"));
    set.add(new Emp(2,"XYZ"));
    set.add(new Emp(1,"PQR"));
    System.out.println(set);
}
```

When I print the set it shows the value for Emp ID 1 as ABC and not PQR

when I check in rt.jar for tree set implementation I notice there seems to be a bug in Implementation as TreeSet Internally uses implementation provided by TreeMap and call put method of TreeMap.

In rt.jar the put code Update the **value** and not **Key** and in TreeSet the value for Key is always passed as **present**

Please help me understand if is there any way to achieve the update in tree set and if my understanding is correct about the bug.

Comment: _Adds the specified element to this set if it is not already present._ What do you make of that?

Comment: when I put the emp object with same ID with different name hash set keep the old object even if the value for Name is changes how can I update the value in TreeSet

Comment: That's the expected behavior of `TreeSet` as the quote from the javadoc from my last comment states.

Comment: if you want to change an element in the set, you need to first remove, then add.

Comment: Yup.  This is working as Java intended, even if it's not what you expected.

Answer (score 0):

As others have already explained, the described behaviour is to be expected and explicitly specified in the JDK API description for class [`TreeSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html]).

If you are looking for a way to keep your collection up to date, check out my [`UpdateableTreeSet`](https://github.com/kriegaex/UpdateableTreeSet) implementation. There are a few articles here on SO which relate to the same problem and also to `UpdateableTreeSet`:

- [Maintaining TreeSet sort as object changes value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2579679/maintaining-treeset-sort-as-object-changes-value/11169301#11169301)
- [Benefit of having a TreeSet over a manually sorted set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12311969/benefit-of-having-a-treeset-over-a-manually-sorted-set/12329909#12329909)
- [Using iterator on a TreeSet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6460320/using-iterator-on-a-treeset/15023790#15023790)